# import settings from config showing some error in my scrapy code

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am  trying to run any scrapy code i am getting this error, don't know why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 282, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named settings
```

can anyone help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

Seems like scrapy can't find `settings.py` file in your scrapy project directory

if you use `tree` command in your project folder:

```
.
├── scrapy.cfg
└── projectname
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── settings.py  # Is this file here?
    └── spiders
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── test_spider_one.py
```

Can you see the file there? Maybe it's deleted or has wrong name?

Also make sure you have correct values set in `scrapy.cfg`
i.e. it should look something like:

```
[settings]
default = projectname.settings
```

Comment: ├── scrapy.cfg
├── twitter
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── items.pyc
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── twitterimpression.py
│       ├── twitterimpression.pyc
│       ├── twitterlocation.py
│       ├── twitterlocation.pyc
│       ├── twitterscrape.py
│       └── twitterscrape.pyc
└── updated_test.csv

file inside i.e. settings.py
BOT_NAME = 'twitter'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['twitter.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'twitter.spiders'

Comment: @KanakSharma, can you edit your question with this output of `tree`? in a comment here, it's very hard to read

Comment: i am pasting it but don't know why it's coming in this format only

Comment: @Granitosaurus - yes, settings.py is on the position it should be

Comment: @KanakSharma what about `scrapy.cfg` content? check my answer edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
├── followers.csv
├── homepage.csv
├── organic.csv
├── scrapy.cfg
├── twitter
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── items.pyc
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── twitterimpression.py
│       ├── twitterimpression.pyc
│       ├── twitterlocation.py
│       ├── twitterlocation.pyc
│       ├── twitterscrape.py
│       └── twitterscrape.pyc
└── updated_test.csv
```

Comment: You should put this in your question, there's an edit button below it.